# NEW-BE calling and displaying an API in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, http

I have been trying to learn but this killing me. I was able to call and display results from an API request using a node.js server with Express, using the code below.

Now I want to do the same thing from a browser so I do not have to have a server running to use this or other APIs.

I just can not find the right commands and syntax. I am not concerned at this time about formatting the results, I just want to get them.

Thanks.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const https = require("https");


app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=85249,us&appid=923779ee1f6a3b4eda92cb153447c361&units=imperial"
    https.get(url, function (responce) {
        console.log(responce.statusCode);
        responce.on("data", function (data) {
            // puts json in a nice formatt  
            const weatherData = JSON.parse(data)
            const temp = weatherData.main.temp
            const location = weatherData.name
            const weather = weatherData.weather[0].main
            const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon
            const imageURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + "@2x.png"

            res.write("<h1> Current temp in " + location + " is " + temp + "</h1>")
            res.write("<p> the sky is " + weather + "<img src =" + imageURL + "></p>")

            res.send()

        })

    });

    // res.send("server running");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(" server listening on port 3000.");
});
```

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here - you can issue HTTP requests from your Node.js server and process the information however you like (as in your example).
But in order to issue HTTP requests from the *browser*, then Node.js is no longer relevant - you need to use Javascript's [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) APIs to do so, please check [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) introduction for more information.

Comment: You are correct, I am looking to eliminate Node.js. Thank you for pointing me in the direction of these commands, I will look at hem when I have a chance. Thank you.